# SQLITE. Выбор 10 ближайших значений к заданному

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

В таблице пользователи есть колонка возраст. Мне нужно получить 10 ближайших значений к этому возрасту (в любом направлении, как старше, так и младше). Я знаю про ф-ю min и max, но они возвращают 1 значение. Ф-я between хорошо подходит, но не понятно какой диапазон задавать. 
Можно с помощью ф-и min и max в цикле к БД обращаться, и каждый раз брать новый минимум и максимум (игнорируя старые), можно так же с помощью ф-и between обрабатывать дальнейший вывод. Но хочется стандартными методами СУБД это сделать, т.к. иначе будет теряться производительность.

Comment: ближайший == минимальное расстояние. Расстояние между числами == модуль разности.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этих целей хорошо подходит функция взятия модуля `ABS`, которая есть и в [MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Mathematical_functions.html) и в [SQLite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-abs/).

Чтобы получить ближайшие значения, надо отсортировать пользователей по модулю разницы между их возрастом и заданным возрастом. С помощью `LIMIT` можно получить только 10 ближайших значений.

```
  SELECT Users.*
    FROM Users
ORDER BY ABS(@age - age)
   LIMIT 10
```

**UPDATE**

Пояснения. Сначала мы вычисляем разницу между возрастом, заданным в переменной `@age` и возрастом каждого пользователя. К сожалению, у нас может получиться и -10 и 1, при этом 1 гораздо ближе к заданному возрасту, чем -10, но -10 формально меньше.

Чтобы избавиться от этой асимметрии, мы берём разницу по модулю. Функция `ABS` возвращает число без знака, в результате -10 превратится в 10, а 1 останется 1.

После функции `ABS` 1 будет меньше 10, то есть разница в один год будет меньше разницы в 10 лет независимо от порядка величин при сравнении.

Клауза `ORDER BY` сортирует пользователей по указанному значению. Обычно сортируют по одному или двум полям, но SQL-сервер способен сортировать записи и по сложным выражениям. В самом начале у нас будут пользователи с наименьшей разницей в возрасте, а затем всё с большей.

Финальный штрих это клауза `LIMIT 10`, который ограничивает размер выборки десятью. Так мы получаем 10 пользователей с наименьшей разницей в возрасте от указанного в переменной `@age`.

Comment: @ДавидШико, это весь запрос. :)

Comment: поясните пожалуйста ответ) Код работает, но хочется логику понять (про ф-ю ABS я знаю). Предположим, мы получили в результате `ORDER BY ABS(5)`, что дальше происходит?

Comment: @ДавидШико. Добавил пояснения в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY age) rn
              FROM sourcetable )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn - ( SELECT rn
             FROM cte
             WHERE user_id = ? ) BETWEEN -10 AND 10
```